# I want REGEX to match dots between each letter C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have Initials field and I want to be sure that the inputted format is like: 
**x.x.** ( capital or small letter )

For example:
the following would be valid: **F.H.** 
the following would be invalid: **FH**  *OR*  **F.H** *OR* **FH.**

I have used these regex forms:

```
\.([a-zA-Z])+\.
([a-zA-Z]\.)+
```

but it did not work for every letter!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The following regex should work: `^([A-Z]{1}\.{1})+`

- `^` begin of line
- `[A-Z]{1}` match capital A through Z exactly one time
- `\.{1}` match a dot (escaped) one time
- `(...)+` repeat the matching group one to unlimited times

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you're not discouraged by the fact that your question was closed. Regex questions are difficult to pose, they easily become a bit too open-ended to fit the format of SO. I suggest playing around in a [regex test environment](https://regex101.com/r/xRattb/1/) so that you can ask more specifically about the matchers that cause problems. Editing the question with your exact use case (abbreviations in text, initials in a form, etc) may also help.

Comment: Thanx @lime, I have edited the post and made a question more specified!

Comment: @Isaac85: great! To make it more answerable still (and thereby increase the chance of it being reopened), I would suggest expanding on the "it did not work for every letter" part. Include a list of problematic strings that _should_ match but _didn't_. That way, someone answering can assess whether they actually address your problem or not.

Comment: (As a sidenote, it may just be that you have a typo in `A-z` vs. `A-Z`. Again, if you fiddle with it in the test environment I linked above, you'll have an easier time telling us *what you tried* and help us [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @lime , I did and hope to see a question open again :)

Comment: Maybe still add some examples of strings that your previous attempts didn't work for? You mention you've tried `([a-zA-Z]\.)+` which looks pretty close to what you want, but it's not clear **why** that didn't work well enough. Did it match something it shouldn't? Did it miss something it should have matched?

Comment: Try `^([a-zA-Z]\.)+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, you mention having used `([a-zA-Z]\.)+`. That regex should match **F.H.**

Depending on the code you're using, you likely need to ensure that you're matching against the **entire** line or string by including the `^$` or `\A\z` metacharacters. In that case you would have `^([a-zA-Z]\.)+$` or `\A([a-zA-Z]\.)+\z`, and that would ensure that **F.H** or **FH.** aren't accidentally matched.

On top of that, you may want to take into account that not all of your users have ASCII-only names. You could then use the `\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` Unicode category to include letters from all languages.

Putting it all together, I would suggest the following regex:

```regex
^(\p{L}\.)+$
```

As you can see in [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/JQxHgE/1), that will match the example strings **F.H.**, **A.B.C.** & **Ö.É.** while not matching **FH**, **F.H**, **FH.** or **A.5.**